# How to fix 'Program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an entry point'?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to coding as you can probably tell and I don;t know how to fix this. Also how come the windows form shows up for like a split second and then disappears?

I've tried putting static void main in different places but none of it seems to work as I don't really know what I'm doing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator_project
{
    public partial class Calculator : Form
    {
        Double value = 0;
        String operation = "";
        bool operation_pressed = false;


        public Calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((result.Text == "0") || (operation_pressed))
                        result.Clear();

            operation_pressed = false;
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            result.Text = result.Text + b.Text;

        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            result.Text = "0";
        }

        private void operator_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            operation = b.Text;
            value = Double.Parse(result.Text);
            operation_pressed = true;
            equation.Text = value + " " + operation;
        }

        private void Button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            equation.Text = "";
            switch (operation)
            {
                case "+":
                    result.Text = (value + Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result.Text = (value - Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result.Text = (value * Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result.Text = (value / Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }//end switch



        }

        private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            result.Text = "0";
            value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the windows form to show me a fully functioning calculator but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Create a new WinForm project, copy Program.cs to your project.

Comment: Have you tampered with the `Program.cs` file in any way?

Comment: Did you get chance to look into my answer. Does it work if not then will delete my answer

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are missing Program.cs file in your windows form application. If you have `Program.cs` file then write `Main()` function inside `Program` class

Your Program.cs file will look like,

```
namespace Calculator_project
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Here Entry point run landing form of your application
            Application.Run(new Calculator()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a new project in Visual Studio and select Visual C# -> Windows Forms Application. This will create the necessary files and build settings to launch your form as an application. While you don't need to use the setup wizard, it will make things easier for you and you can see how all the classes work together.